# Background transition in SCSS doesn't work

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions

I'm trying to use transition in my SCSS file but it doesn't seem to work. I know that gradient is sometimes not supported, so I make "bg-gradienter" to create a background and hope to use it for the transition. However, this code still doesn't work. I also add `width: 50%;` as a debugger; the transition works well on width.

```
&::after {
  @include bg-gradienter (( to bottom left, rgba(6, 55, 105, 0.25) 25%, rgba(8, 57, 106, 1) 100%));
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
&:hover:after {
  width: 50%;
  @include bg-gradienter (( to bottom left, rgba(6, 55, 105, 0.75) 25%, rgba(8, 57, 106, 1) 100%));
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Here is my `bg-gradienter`:

```
@mixin bg-gradienter($args) {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: please add working demo....

Comment: If you are looking to transition the gradient, that's not possible. There's an alternative involving `opacity`. You can look that up.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz  You can transition the position, though

Answer (score 0):

Change `$args` to `$args...` which will allow you to include commas in your argument to `bg-gradienter`:

```
@mixin bg-gradienter($args...) {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient($args), no-repeat;
}
```

and remove the extra parentheses around your arguments in the `@include`